# gcloud Export to Google Storage Bucket from Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

Running this command:

```
 gcloud sql instances export myinstance gs://my_bucket_name/filename.csv -d "mydatabase" -t "mytable"
```

Giving me the following error:

```
  ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.import) ERROR_RDBMS
```

I have manually ran console uploads to the bucket which go fine. I am able to login to the sql instance and run queries. Which makes me think that there are no permission issues. Has anybody ever seen this type of error and knows a way around it?

Note: i have googled for possible situations, and most of them point to either sql or bucket permission issues.

Comment: Nvm. I figured out that i need to make an oauth connection to the instance before interacting with it.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to not leave the question unanswered. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm. I figured out that i need to make an oauth connection (using the json token generated from gcloud api/credentials section) to the instance before interacting with it.

Comment: could you detail what you mean, perhaps giving some example commands, with details redacted? Thanks!